# Reload Datatable with new aaData value

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, post, datatable

How to refresh the Datatable, When new Json data is sent

---

**POST** request Receives data , which is sent to **LoadTable** function to populate the datatable.

```html
function initializeTable(){
 $("#submitbutton").on(
  'click',
  function(){
   $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'rest/log/events',
    data : {
     fromTime : $("#fromTime-filter").val(),
     toTime : $("#toTime-filter").val(),
     Text : $("#search-filter-input").val() 
    },
    
    success : function(data) {
     loadTable(data);
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     showAjaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown,
      $("#error-msg"));
    }
   });
  });
}
```

---

'**data**' is passed to Load function, which loads the data to a table **correctly** the **first time**.
When i submit the POST request the second time, i see New 'data' in the browser console, but the Datatable is **not** **refreshed**.

But when i Refresh the Page(datatable is cleared) and then do a new POST, new data loads normally. I want the new data to be loaded without the need to refresh the page.

```html
function loadTable(data)
{
 $('#report-table').dataTable( {
  bProcessing : true,
  bJQueryUI : true,
  bLengthChange : false,
  bDestory : true,
  bRetrieve : true,
  bStateSave : true,
  oTableTools: {
   sRowSelect: "multi",
   aButtons: [ "select_all", "select_none" ]
  },
  iDisplayLength : 20,
  "aaData": data,
  "aoColumns": [
   { "mData" : "date"  },
   { "mData" : "name"   },
   { "mData" : "type"    },
   { "mData" : "section"   }
  ]
 } );
}
```

Comment: What plugin is $.dataTable? If it's the jQuery DataTables plugin, you'll want to use $('#report-table').dataTable().fnUpdate(data).

Comment: @TAGraves : Yes JQuery Datatables. Where should i add fnUpdate(data)? At the End? I tried with an If else Loop `if (typeof viewTable == 'undefined') { datatable(... } else{$('#report-table')datatable.fnUpdate(data)}` . But it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like you're using DataTables v1.9. Here's how I'd do it:

```js
function loadTable(data)
{
    var table = $('#report-table');
    if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable( table[0] ) ) {
    table.dataTable( {
        bProcessing : true,
        bJQueryUI : true,
        bLengthChange : false,
        bDestory : true,
        bRetrieve : true,
        bStateSave : true,
        oTableTools: {
            sRowSelect: "multi",
            aButtons: [ "select_all", "select_none" ]
        },
        iDisplayLength : 20,
        "aaData": data,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData" : "date"  },
            { "mData" : "name"      },
            { "mData" : "type"          },
            { "mData" : "section"       }
        ]
    } );
    } else {
      table.dataTable().fnUpdate(data);
    }
}
```

Another option:

```js
    function loadTable(data)
    {
        var table = $('#report-table');
        if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable( table[0] ) ) {
        table.dataTable( {
            bProcessing : true,
            bJQueryUI : true,
            bLengthChange : false,
            bDestory : true,
            bRetrieve : true,
            bStateSave : true,
            oTableTools: {
                sRowSelect: "multi",
                aButtons: [ "select_all", "select_none" ]
            },
            iDisplayLength : 20,
            "aaData": data,
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData" : "date"  },
                { "mData" : "name"      },
                { "mData" : "type"          },
                { "mData" : "section"       }
            ]
        } );
        } else {
          table.dataTable().fnDestroy();
          loadTable(data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, though. Happy coding!